# Are there apps similar to Quartz Composer, but for any generic type of data?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, maya, nuke

I have been looking for a desktop GUI app that allows the connection of defined nodes similar to Quartz Composer. The nodes themselves don't need any functionality, I just need it for visual representation.

Some examples:

[image]
http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/inspiration-for-fbp-ui/

[image]

And the node editor of this project:
https://github.com/vurtun/nuklear

Is there a singular term to define this type of graph? I suspect node graph, but google searches for anything with node in it tend to also have .js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems unclear but I'll try to answer it.

There are some apps with **NodeGraph** (aka **NodeTree**/PatchTree) similar to QC: Vuo, Derivative TouchDesigner, VVVV, Troikatronix Isadora, Cycling'74 MaxMSP, etc.

There are also some digital compositing apps for building a **script** with nodes: The Foundry Nuke, Blackmagic Fusion, Apple Shake, etc. Compositing packages have a **DAG** (Directed Acyclic Graph) in their User Interface. DAG is like NodeTree/PatchTree.

**For your tasks you could use The Foundry Nuke. It allows build trees with nodes' names whatever you want. Nuke's nodes are convenient for visual representation.**

[image]

Comment: Facebook's Origami looks nice and it is most similar to QC now that QC has been regressed by Apple.

Comment: I like Origami, however still use "discontinued" QC 4.6.2.

Comment: me too — occasionally, Origami is more limited to UI design.  I need to create a virtual mach with Big Sur b/c QC Editor is full of bugs and crashes on later macOSs. trying to learn Vuo!